# NormalModuleReplacementPlugin does not work when modifying resourceRegExp slightly

Tags: webpack, ckeditor, icons, theming

As officially suggested on the CKEditor5 [homepage](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#how-to-customize-the-ckeditor-5-icons), I want to replace the standard icons which are pre-shipped with several plugins.
Since each plugin (e.g. ckeditor5-core or ckeditor5-alignment) offers its own `.svg` set in [PLUGIN_DIR]/theme/icons, the proposed strategy - to replace them with one's own modified - is understandable and clear:

> (...) use webpack’s NormalModuleReplacementPlugin plugin

```js
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /bold\.svg/,
    '/absolute/path/to/my/icon.svg'
  )
]
```

Based on this code I experimented and ended up with this:

```js
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/,
    resource => {
      console.log(resource.request);
      resource.request = path.resolve(
        THEME_PATH,
        "../../icons/coffee-solid.svg"
      );
    }
  ),
]
```

which cause following (wanted/expected) changes:
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcbbt.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1FLC.png)

partial console output:

```
../../theme/icons/bold.svg
../../theme/icons/italic.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/quote.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/image.svg
../theme/icons/numberedlist.svg
../theme/icons/bulletedlist.svg
../theme/icons/align-justify.svg
../theme/icons/link.svg
(node:10394) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.mapModules: Use Array.from(chunk.modulesIterable, fn) instead
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-right.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-center.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-left.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-full-width.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/low-vision.svg
../theme/icons/drag-handler.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/cancel.svg
../theme/icons/redo.svg
../../../theme/icons/next-arrow.svg
../../../theme/icons/previous-arrow.svg
../theme/icons/undo.svg
../../../theme/icons/dropdown-arrow.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/cancel.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/check.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/check.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/pencil.svg
../../theme/icons/unlink.svg
../../theme/icons/image_placeholder.svg
../theme/icons/align-center.svg
../theme/icons/align-right.svg
../theme/icons/align-left.svg
```

However when I want to restrict the folder to @ckeditor by passing through a respective regex, this is what happens:

```js
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/,
    resource => {
      console.log(resource.request);
      resource.request = path.resolve(
        THEME_PATH,
        "../../icons/coffee-solid.svg"
      );
    }
  ),
]
```

before (see above)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzLev.png)

partial console output (2):

```
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/quote.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/image.svg
(node:10368) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.mapModules: Use Array.from(chunk.modulesIterable, fn) instead
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-right.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-center.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-left.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-full-width.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/low-vision.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/pencil.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/theme/icons/bold.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/theme/icons/italic.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/theme/icons/numberedlist.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/theme/icons/bulletedlist.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/theme/icons/align-justify.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/theme/icons/link.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/theme/icons/drag-handler.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/theme/icons/redo.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/theme/icons/undo.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/icons/next-arrow.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/icons/previous-arrow.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/icons/dropdown-arrow.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/cancel.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/check.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/cancel.svg
@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/check.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/theme/icons/unlink.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/theme/icons/align-center.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/theme/icons/align-right.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/theme/icons/align-left.svg
[PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js![PATH_TO_WS]/workspace/my-cute-editor/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/theme/icons/image_placeholder.svg
```

Why does it happen?

Note: I must use the syntax with resource (the single other alternative as far as I know), because I want to load the icons dynamically later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've answered in the https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1831:

As you can see at the source code of the [`NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin.js) the regexp is tested two times, once before the resolution on the request and once after the resolution on the resource.

As you might see most of the times your function is called after the resolution (as the requests don't match the regexp). The request after the resolution is enhanced by the loaders (that's why the paths are so long and contain weird characters) and actually, this option isn't used anymore. That's why you should change the `result.resource` instead of the `result.request`.

E.g. try the following plugin:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/bold\.svg/,
    result => {
        if ( result.resource ) {
            result.resource = result.resource.replace( 'bold', 'code' );
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're my hero! :)) I almost despaired after fiddling this out for hours and didn't even care to read the source code of the plugin. In the end, I simply modify both, like: `result.request = result.request.replace(/foo/, 'bar'); if (result.resource) result.resource = result.request;` Thank God you encountered this issue ¬2 months before me :p

Comment: day saver, thanks! Wondering why do they still have `resource.request` in the official docs - https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/ ?

Answer (score 1):

for ckeditor5 and webpack5, my implementation for custom ckeditor icons:

```
const customCKEditorIcons = ['bold', 'italic'];  
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/, result => {
        const resource = result.createData.resource;
        if (resource) {
            const iconNamePaths = resource.split('/');
            const iconName = iconNamePaths[iconNamePaths.length - 1].split('.')[0];
            if (customCKEditorIcons.includes(iconName)) {
                result.createData.resource = path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    `path/to/${iconName}.svg`,
                );
            }
        }
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following snippet is useful for everyone who wants 
full control of the appearance of ones CKEditor5's.

```js
/*
THEME_PATH := path to your theme folder (that contains /theme/theme.css)
-> see https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark (use it as a template)
Both REPLACE_ICONS_REGEXP and replaceIcons should be use as described above
*/

const REPLACE_ICONS_REGEXP = /ckeditor5-[^/]+\/theme\/icons\/[^/]+\.svg$/;

function replaceIcons(resource) {
  {
    const [, ckeditorPlugin, svgFileToReplace] = resource.request.match(
      /(ckeditor5-[^/]+)\/theme\/icons\/([^/]+\.svg)$/
    );

    const designatedSvgPath = path.resolve(
      THEME_PATH,
      `../../icons/${svgFileToReplace}`
    );

    try {
      fs.accessSync(designatedSvgPath, fs.constants.F_OK);
      resource.resource = designatedSvgPath; // as ma2ciek suggested
    } catch (err) {
      try {
        // Create mock file to be replaced with themed svg
        fs.writeFileSync(
          path.resolve(THEME_PATH, `../../icons/_${svgFileToReplace}`),
          ""
        );
      } catch (err) {
        err.message =
          `Unable to create icon mock file for ${ckeditorPlugin}.\n` +
          err.message;
        throw err;
      }
    }
  }
}
```